# Pasarela de pago Stripe con Angular

Tags: angular, typescript, stripe

Tengo una aplicación con Angular, estoy intentando implementarle un sistema de pagos, ya me crea el token, se supone que ahora debo de crear un servicio y mandar ese token a stripe para que registre el pago, pero claro nose por donde van los tiros estoy un poco perdido, os dejo mi código actual de stripe donde obtengo el token y el enlace a la web de donde seguí los pasos.

```
  // Realización de renovaciones de licencias con stripe
  loadStripe() {
    if(!window.document.getElementById('stripe-script')) {
      var s = window.document.createElement("script");
      s.id = "stripe-script";
      s.type = "text/javascript";
      s.src = "https://checkout.stripe.com/checkout.js";
      s.onload = () => {
        this.handler = (<any>window).StripeCheckout.configure({
          key: 'MIKEYTEST',
          locale: 'auto',
          token: function (token: any) {
            // You can access the token ID with `token.id`.
            // Get the token ID to your server-side code for use.
            console.log(token)
            alert('Payment Success!!');
          }
        });
      }
      window.document.body.appendChild(s);
    }
  }

  pay(amount) {    
    var handler = (<any>window).StripeCheckout.configure({
      key: 'MIKEYTEST',
      locale: 'es',
      country: 'ES',
      currency: 'eur',
      token: function (token: any) {
        // You can access the token ID with `token.id`.
        // Get the token ID to your server-side code for use.
        console.log(token)
        alert('Token Created!!');
      }
    });
    handler.open({
      name: 'XXXXXX',
      description: 'XXXXXX',
      amount: amount * 100
    });
  }
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

Para crear un enlace de Checkout debes seguir los siguientes pasos:

1. [Backend] Crear una sesión de Checkout desde tu servidor.
2. [Frontend] Redirigir al usuario a Checkout para que puedan ingresar sus datos.
3. [Backend] Procesar el resultado del pago.
4. [Frontend] Mostrar al usuario la página de success/failure.

Puedes ver códigos de ejemplo actualizados en https://stripe.com/docs/payments/checkout/one-time

De todas formas te comento sobre algunos plugins de Angular que parecen simplificar la integración de Checkout utilizando este framework: